# Big files and python

Tags: python

I have a large CSV file(300+ GB) with data (time, OS, ID). What should I do to count the IDs that occur more than 1 time in this file? Which algorithm will not overflow?

Comment: Anything that iterates over the file line by line. It's more about the number of lines and unique ids than the file size.

Comment: How many lines do you have though? 300G may mean billions of records, then you won't have enough memory to keep track of the ids.

Comment: @bereal in worst case, they could use mmap... To both map the file, and another file that stores all ID's, implying that it gets so bad that you need to store things inside a mmaped file and a simple set/dictionary is not enough... Or just crank up size of pagefile for this single task, then you'd have as much memory as your drive can hold... Yeah it would be slower, but 300GB file processing isn't fastest thing in the world in any case. It shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 1):

Simple for loop and reading by the line should do it

```py
result_set = set()
with open(filename, "r") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        # Expected format is smth, smth, important
        splitted_list = line.split(",")
        result_set.add(splitted_list[-1].strip())
print(result_set)
# If file is
# ---
# random, random, important1
# random, random, important2
# ---
# prints:
# {'important2', 'important1'}
```

Unlike readlines(), this does not load the whole file. It will take it's sweet time but it won't crash.